# Ensuring SSH users don't unintentionally affect Apache file ownership

Tags: linux, ubuntu, permissions, apache2

Working with Ubuntu 14.04 in a LAMP configuration.

I have a webroot containing files and directories that all belong to www-data:www-data (i.e. Apache). I have a root SSH account which I primarily use for shell access. Then I have another SSH user on the system that may use SSH for shell or SFTP access.

The problem I'm having is that the SSH user might modify a file with nano via terminal or maybe they'll upload CSV files that end up belonging to their SSH user as opposed to other files in the webroot that belong to www-data. I added their SSH user to the www-data group but it seems that files can still occasionally be found on the system belonging to the user. Might be worth mentioning that I never see them belonging to the root user, just the user account.

How can I ensure that the user has the means to edit files belonging to www-data without affecting permissions? How can I ensure that the files created by the SFTP user are readable by www-data?

Comment: Best option.  Use POSIX ACLs for permissions instead of the ancient, limited *nix user/group/other.  ACLs tend to work better and have less problems where an application will mess things up.

Answer (score 0):

Not a perfect solution, but you can try changing UID and GID of your SFTP user to www-data's (33:33 I assume) directly in `/etc/passwd`.

You'd also need to run chown on user's homedir so user could log in to his account.

```
chown -R 33:33 /home/$username
```

Because of that, all files uploaded/created by this user will have www-data's ownership.

Comment: Thank you, will try. I was curious about this. Because it seems www-data itself is a user, can't I just give www-data a password for SSH access?

Comment: You can indeed. It just seems a bit more convenient to have a dedicated user.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a user that needs to be able to edit files owner by another user, you can make them a member of the same group

```
usermod -a -G group username
```

Just make sure that the group permissions are 6 (for read+write) or 4 (for read only). e.g.:

```
# owner can read+write, group can read+write, others can only read
chmod 664 file

# owner can read+write, group can only read, others can only read
chmod 644 file
```

Alternatively:

```
# give group read+write permissions
chmod g+rw /path/to/file

# give group only read permissions
chmod g+r /path/to/file
```

Comment: Funny how this gets down voted, for no reason.